# Dealing with array size

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I happened to ask myself a question about arrays in c++.
Well, we all know that arrays are fixed collections of something, I say fixed because it is necessary to declare array length when defining arrays.
Well, let's consider an example:

```
char myarray[10] = {'\0'};
int sz = sizeof(myarray); // It is supposed to be 10
```

Well, it is correct, 10 is the number returned by sizeof. This can be done by the compiler because he knows how much space it placed for that variable.

Now consider what happens in this situation:

```
void dosome(mystruct* arr) {
   int elements = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(mystruct);
   for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
      // Do something hoping no overflow will ever occur
   }
}
```

Nice... but I suppose it can be overflow prone. If I pass to this function an array I created in a "normal" way, everything should be fine:

```
mystruct array[20];
dosome(array);
```

No problem. But if I do this:

```
mystruct* array = (mystruct*)malloc(80*sizeof(mystruct));
dosome(array);
```

WHAT HAPPENS???????????????????
I would like to understand how sizeof behaves, this function is evaluated at compile time right??? ok, what happens when I use not an array, but something very cumbersome like a block of data like that one? furthermore, I could realloc it woth another call to malloc and ask to dosome to process that datablock again. Will it work?
I could try it physically, but I would get some exact answer about the behavioir of sizeof.

Thank you.

Comment: In `dosome`, `sizeof(arr)` is `sizeof(mystruct*)` regardless of the way the function is called

Comment: If you develop in C++, then use `new` instead of `malloc` whenever possible. Does your code still misbehave if you define your array like this: `mystruct* array = new mystruct[20];` ?

Comment: icecrime is right, you have wrong expectations

Comment: Well that is crystal clear... unfortunately there are some cases where sizeof does not behave in that way... When I wrote a simple program doing this:
char array[20];
What happened is that I got 20 as answer!!! but array is just a pointer....
sizeof(array); // THIS VALUE IS 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void dosome(mystruct* arr) {
   int elements = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(mystruct);
   for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
      // Do something hoping no overflow will ever occur
   }
}
```

What type does arr have in this example? `mystruct*`! And it's size is most likely 4 or 8. If you want to pass statically/automatically allocated arrays (not new'd) to functions preserving the size so that your trick works, pass by REFERENCE!

```
template <int N>
void dosome(mystruct (& arr) [N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      // Do something . No overflow will occur
   }
}
```

Also note this

```
int a[20];
sizof a; //equals to 20*sizeof(int)
int* b = new int [20];
sizeof b; //equals to sizeof pointer, most likely 4
```

Comment: AHHH ok that's what I wanted to know... so it is different a[20] and *b... compiler can detect size thanks to [number]!! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

it's wrong starting from the `mystruct array[20]` example. Because the function receives a pointer type, and not an array type, it cannot deduce the number of elements in the array. you are actually getting the size of a `mystruct*` when you perform `sizeof(arr)`.

You *can* use templates to write functions which take arrays as parameters, but the suggested way in C++ is to use `vector`s, if I am not wrong.

The "way" to receive arrays as parameters would be to write something like:

```
template <int N> void somefunction(int (&v)[N]);
```

**EDIT** corrected the function declaration. oops.

Comment: The suggested way to pass this kind of thing to a function in C++ is to use pairs of iterators :-) If that fails (e.g. you don't want every function you write to be templated), a vector might do, or a pointer and a length.

Comment: `template <int N> void somefunction(int (&v)[N]);`

Comment: -1: your function declaration is equivalent to this: `template<int N> void somefunction (int* v);`

Answer (score 0):

sizeof is a compile-time operator. And here it computes only the size of a pointer.